# Check a prefect collision between rotating texture and a curve (libgdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing a game where there is a texture that the player need to move around the screen without touching the borders which are black lines and curves.
The figure rotates while the player moves it and the borders are fixed the entire game.
I need a good method to check a prefect collision between the border and the texture.
I tried to make a rectangle around the texture and check for black and green (texture color) pixels that are near each other inside the rectangle but it's too slow.

Comment: Maybe use libgdx built in collision detection? http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html

Comment: Pixelperfect collision is slow. To get a perfomance boost you should sort out all far objects, before checking pixel perfect. So for example if you are near to the left border you cant collide with the right border, as it is to far, so sort it out.

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann I can't use built in collision detection since its a collision between big multiple curves that spreads the whole screen and a rotating texture.